# Customize meta info based on the query string values

Tags: javascript, html, seo, meta-tags, google-crawlers

My website sells stuff and I would like to customize the page title and meta description in certain pages when certain items are viewed. I would want these custom titles and descripts to be listed when shared on other websites. E.g.: Twitter, FB, etc...

Basically I want to customize the title and description based on the query string values. How is this possible? I've looked a js based plugin or similar on github as well but had no luck.

Comment: What is the CMS you're using on your website?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with JavaScript rendered pages is that there's no guarantee a scraper will pick up the meta tags. The headers are read before scripts are run - meaning to lower overhead they likely won't even bother executing it. Better if you write a script that writes customised meta tags to the HTML file.